# How can I change a HTML tag from Combobox

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have an aspx page. which is shortly:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Stack Overflow </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

and there is RadCombobox;

```
 RadCombobox1.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem(){ Text = "Stack", Value = "1" });
 RadCombobox1.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem(){ Text = "Overflow", Value = "2" });
 RadCombobox1.Items.Add(new RadComboBoxItem(){ Text = "Stack Overflow", Value = "2" });
```

When I select second Item which is "Overflow" in my example, 
how can I change < h1> tag?
I want to show in < h1> tag , what I choose from combobox..

Comment: 2) jQuery doesn't speak C#. Please submit the rendered HTML, not the C# code.

Comment: I onlly want to change h1 tag is asp.net when I select any thing from one combobox. and for example the selected item of combobox is "stack" I want to change h1 tag via using jquery ..

Comment: You will need to either change the value of the h1 on postback, in the code behind (set the h1 to `runat="server"` and give it an ID, then reference it to change the html), or use jQuery to detect the change event on the combo box and set the value that way, on the client-side.

Comment: The C# is irrelevant here; please post the rendered HTML. Are you using postbacks? Is that why you've included the C#?

Comment: how can I  to detect the change event with jquery on the combo box on the client-side

Comment: I don't know what a `RadComboBox` is or what it renders as, but assuming it is rendered as a `select` with client-side id `myRadComboBox`, use `$("select#myRadComboBox").on("change", function() {$("h1").html($(this).find("option:selected").text());});`. Note that I haven't tested this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either client side (jquery) to handle the event or a telerik handler (http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/populatingwithdata/autocompletesql/defaultcs.aspx). RadComboBox support lots of client events:
OnClientSelectedIndexChanging
OnClientSelectedIndexChanged
or because Radcombobox is usually rendered as input type=text you can use its on("change" event as per ClarkeyBoy suggested, or onchange event (same thing)

Answer (score 0):

On your RadComboBox markup, add a handler for `onSelectedIndexChanged` as so

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server" onclientselectedindexchanged="OnClientSelectedIndexChanged" .../>

<script>

  function OnClientSelectedIndexChanged(sender, eventArgs) {
     var selectedItem = eventArgs.get_item();
     var selectedItemText = selectedItem != null ? selectedItem.get_text() : sender.get_text();

      //now that you have the text, change H1's text via jQuery
     $('h1').text(selectedItemText);
  }

</script>
```